# Find HTML attribute values using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

I know what I'm trying to do is simple but it's causing me grief. I'd like pull data from HTML using BeautifulSoup. To do that I need to properly use the `.find()` function. Here's the HTML I'm working with:

```html
<div class="audit">

    <div class="profile-info">
        <img class="profile-pic" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/471758097036226560/tLLeiOiL_normal.jpeg" />
        <h4>Ed Boon</h4>
        <span class="screen-name"><a href="http://www.twitter.com/noobde" target="_blank">@noobde</a></span>
    </div>
    
        <div class="followers">
            <div class="pie"></div>
            <div class="pie-data">
                <span class="real number" data-value=73599>73,599</span><span class="real"> Real</span><br />
                <span class="fake number" data-value=32452>32,452</span><span class="fake"> Fake</span><br />
                <h6>Followers</h6>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="score">
            <img src="//twitteraudit-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/f977287de6281fe3e1ef36d48d996fb83dd6a876/img/audit-result-good.png" />
            <div class="percentage good">
                69%
            </div>
            <h6>Audit score</h6>
```

The values I want are `73599` from `data-value=73599`, `32352` from `data-value=32452`, and the `69%` from `percentage good`.

Using past code and online examples, this is what I have so far:

```py
RealValue = soup.find("div", {"class":"real number"})['data-value']
FakeValue = soup.find("audit", {"class":"fake number"})['data-value']
```

Both so far to no effect. I'm not sure how to craft the find in order to pull the `69%` number.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

> `soup.find("div", {"class":"real number"})['data-value']`

Here you are searching for a `div` element, but the `span` has the "real number" class in your example HTML data, try instead:

```
soup.find("span", {"class": "real number", "data-value": True})['data-value']
```

Here we are also checking for presence of `data-value` attribute.

---

To find elements having "real number" or "fake number" classes, you can make a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
for elm in soup.select(".real.number,.fake.number"):
    print(elm.get("data-value"))
```

---

To get the `69%` value:

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "percentage good"}).get_text(strip=True)
```

Or, a CSS selector:

```
soup.select_one(".percentage.good").get_text(strip=True)
soup.select_one(".score .percentage").get_text(strip=True)
```

Or, locating the `h6` element having `Audit score` text and then getting the [preceding sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
soup.find("h6", text="Audit score").previous_sibling.get_text(strip=True)
```

Comment: Just for anyone who made the same mistake I did, the arguments passed into `soup.find()` needed to be double quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to identify the class labels in a `find_all()` call on the soup object. This finds all span tags with class values "real number"  or "fake number".

```py
import re
spans = soup.find_all('span', {"class": re.compile("[real|fake] number")})
[span['data-value'] for span in spans]    # ['73599', '32452']
```

On the other hand, with the CSS selector, we can even get different tags with different classes:

```py
mytags = soup.select('span.real.number, span.fake.number, div.percentage.good')
[tag.text.strip() for tag in mytags]     # ['73,599', '32,452', '69%']
```