# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' within tbody

Tags: python, web-scraping, attributeerror

I am kind off a newbie within the python field and try to set up a webscraping tool. So I am experimenting some codes.

```
import requests
import bs4

website = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website.text, "html.parser")

leaderboard = soup.find("table", {id: "stats-table player-ratings-table"})
tbody = leaderboard.find("tbody")

for tr in tbody.find.all('tr'):
    team = tr.find.all('td')[0].text.strip()
    maps = tr.find.all('td')[1].text.strip()
    kd = tr.find.all('td')[3].text.strip()
    rating = tr.find.all('td')[4].text.strip()

    print(team, maps, kd, rating)
```

I get the following error, any help? I use 2.7.

```
 File "/Users/*****/Python/New Webscraping/WebS.py", line 11, in <module>
    tbody = leaderboard.find("tbody")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: See [Python: Attribute Error - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949252/python-attribute-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-something?rq=1)

Comment: Your `leaderboard` object was set to `None`, probably because the output of the `find` did not return what you expected. Try to print your soup and check what's wrong with it...

Comment: You simply confused `id` and `class` attributes...

Comment: Maybe ven better duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup (the link mentioned above explains what the error means, this link explains why `find()` returns `None`).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following to get your desired output. I ignored the first tr by indexing it like `[1:]` as there is no `td` within it. Moreover, there is no such method `.find.all()` in `BeautifulSoup`. you can use `.find_all()` or `.findAll()` instead.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
for tr in soup.find("table",class_="player-ratings-table").find_all("tr")[1:]:
    team = tr.find_all('td')[0].text.strip()
    maps = tr.find_all('td')[1].text.strip()
    kd = tr.find_all('td')[3].text.strip()
    rating = tr.find_all('td')[4].text.strip()
    print(team, maps, kd, rating)
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of the website you're trying to scrape it looks like the keyword you're looking for is not `id` but `class`:

```
<table class="stats-table player-ratings-table">
```

So you should change your code to:

```
leaderboard = soup.find("table", {'class': "stats-table player-ratings-table"})
```

Also you should change the `find.all` to `findAll`.

Answer (score 0):

Reading errors is a skill that will benefit you greatly when programming. The important parts of the error, for you, are:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'` on `line 11` of `...WebS.py`

And the actual line of code that the error was thrown on: `tbody = leaderboard.find("tbody")`.

The attribute `find` was called on the reference `leaderboard` on that line, and the error is telling you that `NoneType`s have no `find`, so that means `leaderboard == None`.

To further break down the error, if you were still confused (on a different error), you should read about what comes before that colon, in this case `AttributeError`. But most frequently, you should google the error.

Answer (score -1):

It means that there are some items that do not have team or maps or kid or rating.
You should do 'error handling'

```
import requests
import bs4

website = requests.get("https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams")

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website.text, "html.parser")

leaderboard = soup.find("table", {id: "stats-table player-ratings-table"})
tbody = leaderboard.find("tbody")

for tr in tbody.find.all('tr'):
    try:
        team = tr.find.all('td')[0].text.strip()
    except AttributError:
        team = ''
    
    try:
        maps = tr.find.all('td')[1].text.strip()
    except AttributError:
        maps = ''

    try:
        kd = tr.find.all('td')[3].text.strip()
    except AttributError:
        kd = ''

    try:
        rating = tr.find.all('td')[4].text.strip()
    except AttributError:
        rating = ''

    print(team, maps, kd, rating)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You should know ErrorHandling method. !!!