# Printing all text from a class in HTML using python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to print all the text from a certain class on a page but can't find how,

```
dmenuhtml = BeautifulSoup(dmenu, 'html.parser')

#print(dmenuhtml)

#using find function to parse through the html
allday_breakfast = dmenuhtml.find()
#converting to text
allday_breakfast2 = allday_breakfast.text.strip()

print ("The All Day Breakfast today features...\n")
print(allday_breakfast)
```

I'm not familiar with HTML so I'm not sure what toput in the find brackets?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understand the Find() function in Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup)

Comment: Did you see the official documentation for the [`find()` method here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#find\(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20**kwargs\)) ? It gives several examples

Comment: What are you trying to "find" on the webpage? You don't need to use any function to "parse through the html", `print(dhmenuhtml)` will parse all the HTML. Use `find()` method to ***search for*** a specific part of the webpage. like important or interesting contents, phrases, HTML elements, tags, etc. Take a look at all the possibilities in the documentation: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: I'll take a look through the documentation. I'm trying to take all the text, it's a menu that changes daily and I want to pull the text everyday to email to myself so I know the menu

Comment: Ok, let us know if you get stuck. If you know the tag or id of the `menu` element in the webpage html source code, then you can put that menu tag as a parameter `.find(id="dmenu")` or whatever the menu name is.

Comment: So, it looks like all the names of the items are stored as "span.item__name", is there a way to pull all instances of this? Then if I only want six, it looks like I can do .find(x, limit = 6) ?

Comment: to find ***all*** instances use `dmenuhtml.find_all()`, and yes, with the limit will also work. altogether: try `allday_breakfast = dmenuhtml.find_all('span', limit=6)`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [i.text for i in dmenuhtml.findAll('div',{'class':'/class_name/'})]
```

try something like this. you need to know where your text is located in the html.