# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to python and only have a couple hours of experience. I've been creating a script that scrapes the Air Quality readings for my country directly.

I am trying to run this command within my script:

```
psi = soup.find("div", {"class": "panel-stats-value-content"}).text
```

Though when I run it, it responds with:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

How can I fix this? So that `.text` will work?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup

Comment: this error means that when you tried to find this thing "("div", {"class": "panel-stats-value-content"})", there was not a single result matching with the above conditions, so you're doing something wrong while finding the div classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is raised because `BeautifulSoup.find()` is unable to find any `div` elements with the class of `panel-stats-value-content` in the document, so returns `NoneType`.

When you try and call a method on a `NoneType`, it will raise the above error, but with the method whatever you called on it.

To fix this you need to make sure that the `div` element's class is correct.