# I need help understanding soup.find() for webscraping, and how this works exactly to find the right information

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to webscraping, HTML, Javascript, and CSS, so I am unsure what kind of information I am missing exactly, to solve my issue. I'm using beautiful soup to scrape some web pages, where I have the web page open, so I can see exactly where and what kind of data to pull, using beautiful soup's function, soup.find(). I got some soup.find() calls to work, but the ones below returned NONE, and I would like clarification on why it did so.

Is there something I'm not understanding about HTML or the use of beautifulsoup?

I have looked at the beautiful soup documentation, which referred me to the

```
soup.find(name,{"attributeName":"attribute", ... "attributeName4":"attribute4"}, recursive=True, text=None)
```

From my understanding,

```
"name"="tag" (in purple), and "attributeName"="attribute" (in orange).
```

I have already tested the below code, and it returns NONE.

I added the following piece of code, using selenium:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.cp_ratings.rated')
```

Below are snippet of code I am trying to scrape and the corresponding unsuccessful lines of code that returned NONE:

```
<div class="cp_ratings  rated" data-rating_value="8" data-js="ratings" data-read_only="true" data-bib_id="95103005" data-inline_messaging="true" testid="widget_averagerating">
  <div class="rating_wrapper rating_large rating_average" data-js="rating-wrapper">
    <div class=" rating_icons" data-js="rating-icons" style="width: 80%;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To get the value=8 from "data-rating_value", I have tried the following pieces of code:

(1) `item = soup.find("span",{"class":"cp_ratings   rated"})`

(2) `item = soup.find("div",{"class":"cp_ratings   rated"})`

(And as referenced by this stack overflow question): [Understand the Find() function in Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup)

(3) `item = soup.find("span",{"class":"cp_ratings.rated","data-rating_value":True,"data-js":"ratings","data-read_only":"false","data-bib_id":"1143905005","data-inline_messaging":"false","testid":"widget_rating"})`

(4) `item = soup.find("span",{"class":"cp_ratings   rated","data-rating_value":True,"data-js":"ratings","data-read_only":"false","data-bib_id":"1143905005","data-inline_messaging":"false","testid":"widget_rating"})`

I expected to get the `data-rating_value` and the `value=0`in the code above, but I got NONE instead. From my understanding, you have to put all the attributes in the tag to find a result, but this isn't happening in this case.

Link to webpage: https://epl.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1142125005?active_tab=bib_info#

Comment: you will need to extract the data-rating_value attribute to get the 8 but can you share the url? If the element is dynamic then it won't be there with requests. Try turning off javascript on the page and refreshing the page - is the element still visible?

Comment: [link](https://epl.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1142125005?active_tab=bib_info#)

Answer (score 0):

For the first problem you need to share your html.
For second problem 
Try `soup.find('div', {'class' : 'cp_ratings rated'})`  instead of `soup.find("span",{"class":"cp_ratings   rated"})`

Comment: I tried that, I wasn't successful. I made more edits to the question above to show what I've done since then - I solved the first problem, I'm still stuck on the second, but I've actually used selenium since then (that was how I was able to solve the first problem).

Answer (score 0):

The rating comes from the style width percentage applied against a max star rating of 5

```
import requests, re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

p = re.compile(r'\d+')
r = requests.get('https://epl.bibliocommons.com/item/show/1142125005?active_tab=bib_info#')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
title = soup.select_one('.item_bib_title').text.strip()
rating = int(p.findall(soup.select_one('.rating_icons')['style'])[0])/100 * 5 #5 is max start full width i.e. 100%
print(rating)
```