# I was using BeautifulSoup package and I get this attributeError

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, attributeerror

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.jumia.com.ng/ergonomic-office-swivel-chair-universal-mpg200557.html")

content = request.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")

element = soup.find("span", {"dir" : "ltr", "data-price" : "", "class" : "-b -ltr -fs24"})

print(element.text)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/EMMRAWL/PycharmProjects/Price of Chair/scr/app.py", line 9, in <module>

print(element.text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: `.find` returns `None` if there is no match find. So make sure your match is find or not like `if element:` like this.

Comment: Thanks. So maybe, the link is incorrect, or the element dictionary

Comment: I've seen the error

Comment: element = soup.find("span", {"dir" : "ltr", "data-price" : "", "class" : "-b -ltr -tar -fs24"})

Comment: there is a "-tar" between  "-ltr" and "-fs24" in the element dictionary

Comment: Check this out hope it will help you [Understand the Find() function in Beautiful Soup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup)

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS selector which is much faster in getting output.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.jumia.com.ng/ergonomic-office-swivel-chair-universal-mpg200557.html")

content = request.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element=soup.select_one('span.-b.-ltr.-fs24[dir="ltr"][data-price]')
print(element.text)
```

**Output**:

```
₦ 16,000
```

---

To use find() try below code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get("https://www.jumia.com.ng/ergonomic-office-swivel-chair-universal-mpg200557.html")

content = request.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.find("span", attrs={"dir" : "ltr",  "data-price" : "" , "class" : "-fs24"})
print(element.text)
```

**Output**:

```
₦ 16,000
```