# Scraping a HTML table. All classes have the same name, but different content. How to scrape the content?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
[<div class="d-row js-search-row js-acc-wrapper" id="stocks-row-1">
   <div class="d-cell js-cell js-acc-activator" data-label="Instrument">0001</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-cell js-target" data-label="Company">CK Hutchison</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Min traded quantity
      ">30</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Retail clients">
      20%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Professional clients">
      10%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Long position swap">-0.018743</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Short position swap">-0.009970</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Market hours *">
      1:30 am to 8:10 am
   </div>
</div>
,
<div class="d-row js-search-row js-acc-wrapper" id="stocks-row-2">
   <div class="d-cell js-cell js-acc-activator" data-label="Instrument">0002</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-cell js-target" data-label="Company">CLP Holdings Ltd.</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Min traded quantity
      ">25</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Retail clients">
      20%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Professional clients">
      10%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Long position swap">-0.023541</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Short position swap">-0.012522</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Market hours *">
      1:30 am to 8:10 am
   </div>
</div>
,
<div class="d-row js-search-row js-acc-wrapper" id="stocks-row-3">
   <div class="d-cell js-cell js-acc-activator" data-label="Instrument">0003</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-cell js-target" data-label="Company">The Hong Kong and China Gas Company Ltd.</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Min traded quantity
      ">100</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Retail clients">
      20%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Margin - Professional clients">
      10%                    
   </div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Long position swap">-0.003874</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Short position swap">-0.002061</div>
   <div class="d-cell hidden js-target" data-label="Market hours *">
      1:30 am to 8:10 am
   </div>
</div>]
```

The above are three rows I scraped from a much larger table. `"data-label"` is the column name and each data label has a value.

The original table looks like this [Link to Table](https://www.trading212.com/en/Trading-Instruments?id=3)

[image]

I am trying to get the values for each row however, the div class are the exact same for most of them.

In the sample above, you can see most cells have the class `d-cell hidden js-target`.

I can find the `Instrument` and `Company` data because they have their own `class`. The below works great:

```
instrument = soup.findAll("div",{'class':'d-cell js-cell js-acc-activator'})
company = soup.findAll("div",{'class':'d-cell hidden js-cell js-target'})
```

But the rest of the data all share the same class, but differ in the attribute called `data-label`.

If I just use the class, I get all the data mixed together.

```
soup.findAll("div",{'class':'d-cell hidden js-target'})
```

Which won't work.

For example, how do I get only the `Min traded quantity` and then get only `Margin` etc separately?

I can't figure out how to use the `data-label` attribute with `findAll`.

Here is my attempt at using `data-label` to get the `Min traded quantity`, which is a kind of workaround to the stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34301815/understand-the-find-function-in-beautiful-soup)

```
min_traded_quantity = soup.findAll("div",{'class':'d-cell hidden js-target','data-label':"Min traded quantity"})`
```

Results in an empty list.

I honestly don't know what to google because I don't know what this `data-label` thing is. The answers I find are kind of similar to my problem, but don't work for me.  Is it another type of class? Can I reference it somehow with `Findall` ?

I have also removed the `class` in findall, and just use the `data-label`, which doesn't work:

```
min_traded_quantity = soup.findAll("div",{'data-label':"Min traded quantity"})`
```

Any advice?

Yes I am a complete newbie at Beautful soup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just grab the div that represents a row and then find all `divs` within that row and you're done.

Here's how:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tabulate import tabulate


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36"
}

url = "https://www.trading212.com/en/Trading-Instruments?id=3"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "d-row js-search-row js-acc-wrapper"})
columns = [
    " ".join(i.getText(strip=True).split()) for i 
    in soup.find("div", {"class": "d-row hidden-heading"})
]
parsed_table = [
    [i.getText(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("div")] for row in table
]

print(tabulate(parsed_table, headers=columns))
```

Output:

```
Instrument    Company                                           Min traded quantity  Margin - Retail clients    Margin - Professional clients      Long position swap    Short position swap  Market hours *
------------  ----------------------------------------------  ---------------------  -------------------------  -------------------------------  --------------------  ---------------------  -------------------
0001          CK Hutchison                                                       30  20%                        10%                                         -0.018743              -0.00997   1:30 am to 8:10 am
0002          CLP Holdings Ltd.                                                  25  20%                        10%                                         -0.023541              -0.012522  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0003          The Hong Kong and China Gas Company Ltd.                          100  20%                        10%                                         -0.003874              -0.002061  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0004          The Wharf Ltd.                                                     50  20%                        10%                                         -0.006152              -0.003273  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0011          Hang Seng Bank Ltd.                                                10  20%                        10%                                         -0.044209              -0.023516  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0016          Sun Hung Kai Properties Ltd.                                       15  20%                        10%                                         -0.033863              -0.018012  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0023          Bank of East Asia, Ltd.                                           100  20%                        10%                                         -0.005545              -0.00295   1:30 am to 8:10 am
0066          MTR Corporation Ltd.                                               50  20%                        10%                                         -0.013814              -0.007348  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0175          Geely Automobile Holdings Ltd.                                    150  20%                        10%                                         -0.006766              -0.003599  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0267          CITIC Ltd.                                                        250  20%                        10%                                         -0.002019              -0.001074  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0291          China Resources Beer Company Ltd.                                  50  20%                        10%                                         -0.020097              -0.01069   1:30 am to 8:10 am
0388          Hong Kong Exchanges and Clearing Ltd.                              10  20%                        10%                                         -0.12393               -0.06592   1:30 am to 8:10 am
0390          China Railway Group Ltd.                                            1  20%                        10%                                         -0.001255              -0.000668  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0688          China overseas                                                     50  20%                        10%                                         -0.006303              -0.003352  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0700          Tencent Holdings Ltd                                               10  20%                        10%                                         -0.177066              -0.089409  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0728          China Telecom Corporation Limited                                   1  20%                        10%                                         -0.000769              -0.000409  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0762          China Unicom (Hong Kong) Limited.                                   1  20%                        10%                                         -0.001519              -0.000808  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0857          PetroChina Company Limited.                                         1  20%                        10%                                         -0.000808              -0.00043   1:30 am to 8:10 am
0883          CNOOC Ltd.                                                        150  20%                        10%                                         -0.002516              -0.001339  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0916          China Longyuan Power Group Corporation Limited                      1  20%                        10%                                         -0.001511              -0.000804  1:30 am to 8:10 am
0939          China Construction Bank Corporation                                 1  20%                        10%                                         -0.002019              -0.001074  1:30 am to 8:10 am
1088          China Shenhua Energy Company Ltd.                                 100  20%                        10%                                         -0.004984              -0.002651  1:30 am to 8:10 am
1299          AIA Group Ltd.                                                    100  20%                        20%                                         -0.028828              -0.015334  1:30 am to 8:10 am
1337          Razer Inc.                                                          1  20%                        5%                                          -0.000838              -0.000423  1:30 am to 8:10 am
1810          Xiaomi Corp                                                         1  50%                        50%                                         -0.008597              -0.002866  1:30 am to 8:10 am
1COV          Covestro AG                                                         1  20%                        5%                                          -0.013721              -0.008687  8:00 am to 4:30 pm
21P1          Aurora Cannabis, Inc.                                               1  50%                        50%                                         -0.006535              -0.001592  8:00 am to 4:30 pm
2318          Ping An Insurance Company of China, Ltd.                           25  20%                        10%                                         -0.031015              -0.016497  1:30 am to 8:10 am
2388          BOC Hong Kong Ltd.                                                 10  20%                        5%                                          -0.008086              -0.004301  1:30 am to 8:10 am
2628          China Life Insurance Company Ltd.                                 150  20%                        10%                                         -0.005885              -0.00313   1:30 am to 8:10 am
2914          Japan Tobacco Inc                                                   1  20%                        5%                                          -0.472853              -0.538543  12:00 am to 6:00 am
3328          Bank of Communications Co., Ltd.                                  300  20%                        10%                                         -0.001405              -0.000747  1:30 am to 8:10 am
3333          China Evergrande Group                                              1  20%                        5%                                          -0.004829              -0.001909  1:30 am to 8:10 am
3382          Seven & i Holdings Co., Ltd.                                        1  20%                        5%                                          -0.765264              -0.871578  12:00 am to 6:00 am
3836          China Harmony New Energy Auto Holding Ltd                           1  20%                        5%                                          -0.001337              -0.000711  1:30 am to 8:10 am
3988          Bank Of China Ltd.                                               1000  20%                        10%                                         -0.000893              -0.000475  1:30 am to 8:10 am
4063          Shin-Etsu Chemical Co Ltd                                           5  20%                        20%                                         -3.92842               -4.47417   12:00 am to 6:00 am
4452          Kao Corp                                                           10  20%                        20%                                         -1.73538               -1.97647   12:00 am to 6:00 am
4502          Takeda Pharmaceutical Company Limited                               1  20%                        5%                                          -0.851379              -0.969656  12:00 am to 6:00 am
4503          Astellas Pharma Inc                                                 1  20%                        5%                                          -0.332695              -0.378914  12:00 am to 6:00 am
```

**Bonus:**

> This works with any `id` on that page. For example, try this url https://www.trading212.com/en/Trading-Instruments?id=1

Comment: Thank you, this works amazingly well and very tidy! Playing around with your solution also helped me figure out how to access the `data-label` attribute. You can add this to your solution too if you like. For example, here we are only taking `Instrument` and `Company`..... `parsed_table= [[i.getText(strip=True) for i in row.find_all("div") if i['data-label'] in ['Instrument','Company']] for row in table]`

Comment: I'm glad you find it useful and well done on narrowing down your results. Happy coding!