# How to scrape content from a website with no class or id specified in attribute with BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, export-to-csv

I want to scrape separate content like- text in 'a' tag (ie. only the name- "42mm Architecture") and 'scope of services, types of built projects, Locations of Built Projects, Style of work, Website' as CSV file headers and its content for a whole webpage.

The elements have no Class or ID associated with it. So I am kind of stuck on how to extract those details properly, also there are those 'br' and 'b' tags in between.

There are multiple 'p' tags before and after the block of code provided. Here is the [website](https://www.re-thinkingthefuture.com/top-architects/top-architecture-firms-in-india-part-1/).

```
<h2>
  <a href="http://www.dezeen.com/tag/design-by-42mm-architecture" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
   42mm Architecture
  </a>
  |
  <span style="color: #808080;">
   Delhi | Top Architecture Firms/ Architects in India
  </span>
 </h2>
 <!-- /wp:paragraph -->
 <p>
  <b>
   Scope of services:
  </b>
  Architecture, Interiors, Urban Design.
  <br/>
  <b>
   Types of Built Projects:
  </b>
  Residential, commercial, hospitality, offices, retail, healthcare, housing, Institutional
  <br/>
  <b>
   Locations of Built Projects:
  </b>
  New Delhi and nearby states
  <b>
   <br/>
  </b>
  <b>
   Style of work
  </b>
  <span style="font-weight: 400;">
   : Contemporary
  </span>
  <br/>
  <b>
   Website
  </b>
  <span style="font-weight: 400;">
   :
   <a href="https://www.42mm.co.in/">
    42mm.co.in
   </a>
  </span>
 </p>
```

So how is it done using BeautifulSoup4?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34301866/5345646?

Comment: @Mooncrater the website I m looking to scrape doesn't have "class or id" attributes.

Comment: You can still scrape on the basis of tags though. If you know that it's going to be a `a` tag, you can scrape that. Are there other `a` tags in the page?

Comment: @Mooncrater there is 1 'a' tag, followed by span, p. but throughout the page, it is not consistent, nor do they follow any certain pattern.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "inconsistent". Please elaborate and also show the code you've written so far so we can see where you might be having difficulty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one was a bit of a time consuming one! The webpage is not complete and it has less tags and identifiers. To add more on that they haven't even spell checked the content **Eg.** One place has a heading `Scope of Services` and another place has `Scope of services` and there are many more like that! So what I have done is a crude extraction and I'm sure it would help you if you have the idea of paginating also.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

page = requests.get('https://www.re-thinkingthefuture.com/top-architects/top-architecture-firms-in-india-part-1/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

# there are many h2 tags but we want the one without any class name
h2 = soup.find_all('h2', class_= '')

headers = []
contents = []
header_len = []
a_tags = []

for i in h2:
    if i.find_next().name == 'a':             # to make sure we do not grab the wrong tag
        a_tags.append(i.find_next().text)
        p = i.find_next_sibling()
        contents.append(p.text)
        h =[j.text for j in  p.find_all('strong')]   #  some headings were bold in the website
        headers.append(h)
        header_len.append(len(h))

# since only some headings were in bold the max number of bold would give all headers
headers = headers[header_len.index(max(header_len))]

# removing the : from headings
headers = [i[:len(i)-1] for i in headers]

# inserted a new heading
headers.insert(0, 'Firm')

# n for traversing through headers list
# k for traversing through a_tags list
n =1
k =0

# this is the difficult part where the content will have all the details in one value including the heading like this
"""
Scope of services: Architecture, Interiors, Urban Design.Types of Built Projects: Residential, commercial, hospitality, offices, retail, healthcare, housing, InstitutionalLocations of Built Projects: New Delhi and nearby statesStyle of work: ContemporaryWebsite: 42mm.co.in
"""
# thus I am splitting it using the ':' and then splicing it from the start of the each heading

contents = [i.split(':') for i in contents]
for i in contents:
    for j in i:
        h = headers[n][:5]
        if i.index(j) == 0:
            i[i.index(j)] = a_tags[k]
            n+=1
            k+=1
        elif h in j:
            i[i.index(j)] = j[:j.index(h)]
            j = j[:j.index(h)]
            if n < len(headers)-1:
                n+=1
    n =1

    # merging those extra values in the list if any
    if len(i) == 7:
        i[3] = i[3] + ' ' + i[4]
        i.remove(i[4])

# writing into csv file
# if you don't want a line space between each row then add newline = '' argument in the open function below
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:   
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(contents)
```

This was the output:

[image]

If you want to paginate then just add the page number to the end of the url and you'll be good!

```
page_num = 1
while page_num <13:
    page = requests.get(f'https://www.re-thinkingthefuture.com/top-architects/top-architecture-firms-in-india-part-1/{page_num}/')

    # paste the above code starting from soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

    page_num +=1
```

Hope this helps, let me know if there's any error.

**EDIT 1:**
I forgot to say the most important part sorry, if there is a tag with `no class` name then you can still get the tag with what I have used in the code above

```
h2 = soup.find_all('h2', class_= '')
```

This just says that give me all the `h2` tags which does not have a class name. This itself can sometimes be a unique identifier as we are using this `no class value` to identify it.

Comment: Thank You so much.
tried to Paginate it, but the Site is not made properly, there are a lot of inconsistencies regarding h2 tag on further pages.

Comment: Saw that one coming. You can just try to get as much as proper data you can and then manipulate them using `re` module. That module will be helpful for you when you want to take only a subset of a string matching a particular pattern.

Comment: Hey, can I ask for a little more help? 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/68975727/16626943
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this example as a basis how to scrape the informations from that page:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/endorsing-bodies-start-up/start-up"

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
parent = soup.select_one("div.govspeak")

mapping = {"sector": "sectors", "endorses businesses": "endorses businesses in"}

all_data = []
for h3 in parent.select("h3"):
    name = h3.text
    link = h3.a["href"] if h3.a else "-"

    ul = h3.find_next("ul")
    if ul and ul.find_previous("h3") == h3 and ul.parent == parent:
        li = [
            list(map(lambda x: mapping.get((i := x.strip()), i), v))
            for li in ul.select("li")
            if len(v := li.get_text(strip=True).split(":")) == 2
        ]
    else:
        li = []

    all_data.append({"name": name, "link": link, **dict(li)})


df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]